# i can not get the token when i send it to the deployed api on heroku

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, heroku

Hello I have a problem with my API that I deployed on heroku it does not take the token that is sent in header on heroku but localhost it works.
[image]

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: you are storing it in the wrong place in your api tester. put it under headers, where key is token, and value is the value you need.

Comment: I already try and it does not change anything

Comment: `$token = $request->header('token');` use this

Comment: oh and change your function testToken to thisl; `function testToken(Request $request)` and instantiate at the top of your file right after namespace this; `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: thanks it worked with postman i would like to know now how sent in header with axios in viewjs because i do like that

Comment: const response = await axios.get(url, {
      headers: {
        token: localStorage.token
      }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200937/discussion-between-noplz-and-udhayan-nair).